# Horizontally and vertically center bootstrap 4 columns in consecutive rows

Tags: html, flexbox, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment, centering

I'm trying to simply center justify and align two bootstrap columns inside a container. The columns are in different rows.

The grid layout is

```
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card">
                    world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the cards are just to outline the containers.

I'm aware there are MANY questions on vertical alignment, and I may have missed the one that contains the answer I need. But my take away from most of them is that the parent needs to have some height.
The following works just fine if you have only one row, because you can center the column in the 100% height row. But if you have two rows, it doesn't so well, since each column is centered in its own row, and the rows are each the height of the window.

```
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card">
                    world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I wish I could just move the `justify-content-center align-items-center` up to the container, but alas that doesn't seem to do anything.

So, please help me, how can I place these flush, one on top of the other, smack in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Always give the height through the `inner element`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a good way to do this using Bootstrap's build in flexboxes.

```
<div class="container d-flex h-100 flex-column">
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">ITEM A</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">ITEM B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card">ITEM C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
</div>
```

We have two buffer flex rows, with flex-grow-1.  Each of these rows will expand (with the same weight) to fill the top and bottom portions equally.  Each of the content rows in the middle will have the height of their content.

The end result is the ITEM cards centered both vertically and horizontally on the screen.  Because they are within individual rows, you can adjust margins/padding as necessary (by default they cards end up next to each other vertically.

[Example screenshot of the above code in bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RCOS.png)

You could potentially do this one with one row + column and an internal flexbox, but that gives you less control over how the individual cards appear in relation to each other.

EDIT: d-flex makes the container a flex container around it's child rows, and flex-column makes the children render and stretch vertically rather than horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution is to make the **rows 50% height** instead...

```
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    hello
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card">
                    world
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/7POJtgNaQI

**Or,** the **flexbox** method would be to use Bootstrap flex-grow-1 class. Also you don't need the height on the body. Just use `min-vh-100` on the container...

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">
                world
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/n1eL2Jakuo

Answer (score 1):

Always give the height through the `inner element` height, If I will give the `height` on `container` class element, it won't work, so let the `container` depend on the `inner element's` height, So try like this.

[image: Set Container Height through Inner Element's Height]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container mt-3">
 <div class="col-12" style="min-height: 180px;">
  <div
   class="row bg-success position-absolute w-100 h-100 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">

   <div class="col-6 pr-2">
    <div class="card text-center">
     hello
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-6 pl-2">
    <div class="card text-center">
     world
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hope you will understand this tiny mess, and so it would help you.

Comment: This places two columns side-by-side inside the same row. I have no trouble doing that. What I'm looking for is one on top of the other, ideally in different rows.

Comment: That is simply simple, but you didn't mention earlier this scenario

Comment: I explicitly specified one on top of the other and in different rows several times in my post as well as in the title. But if there's some way you think I can make the question more clear please let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: Dear kag0, you didn't have mentioned the breakpoint behavior above,  and you are reaching to your post 4 days after to take a update, overall make this change above card div 'col-12 col-md-6 pr-2 px-md-3' and same for pl-2 class line also....hope it would help you.